# how to call the function from IDAPython with passing arguments by manually push them to the stack

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

would you please tell me how to call the function from IDAPython code ?

I want to simulate it by manually push to stack as the two arguments and calling the function.

Comment: Are you interested in getting the result of the decryption for the specific use-case or in general how to use the IDAPython API to emulate/call a function?

Comment: Of course I am interested in the general method, but first I would like to know how to write the actual code by IDApython that calls the DecryptFuntion in the specific case above, passing any two arguments (Push).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manual pushing, you should be able to use [Appcall](https://www.hex-rays.com/blog/practical-appcall-examples/).